# UITableView Not Loading Data From Segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a sequence where the user logs in and then they are brought to view showing a UITableView via a segue. I am trying to inject data from the login screen to the table after a successful login.

In the login view...

```
    func transitionToHome() {
    print("Hey you logged in!")=
        
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess", sender: self)
    
    self.navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    
}

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
    vc.models = [(title: "title", note: "Note")]
}
```

And in the Home Screen view

```
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var newNoteButton: UIButton!

var models: [(title: String, note: String)] = [] 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    title = "Notes"

}
```

I have tried to call table.reloadData() in the the viewDidLoad, as well as in viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear. Neither has worked.

I also have printed out models in the viewDidLoad and I saw that the data is being correctly passed to the view controller. But,I cannot get the table to load this data when the view controller is loaded from the segue.

Comment: If *the data is being correctly passed to the view controller* then the issue is related to the table view data source. And a tuple as data source is bad practice.

Comment: @vadian what is the best way to setup the data source? Sorry, I am very new to iOS dev and I have been trying to learn through YouTube and Stack Overflow.

I am importing data from firestore

Comment: The recommended way is a custom struct

Answer (score 0):

If you models data prints correctly in viewDidLoad() you should be able to configure a tableview cell with the data in the dataSource implementation. See sample extension for the dataSource implementation below. Make sure you provide a reuse identifier to your prototype cell in the storyboard.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "This is a cell primary text"
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    return cell
}
```